# Django not a valid value for a primary key error in ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, forms

I created a form consisting of two ModelMultipleChoiceFields of all the countries in the world.

But after a POST request, Django doesn't deem the form valid with the error:

"Algeria" is not a valid value for a primary key

(or whichever country I select). Here is my form:

```
class ComparisonForm(forms.Form):

    country_1 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=WorldBorder.objects.values_list('name',flat=True)
    )
    country_2 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=WorldBorder.objects.values_list('name',flat=True)
    )
```

The list of countries is drawn from the db, which works fine. And my views:

```
def lookup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ComparisonForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            results = form.save(commit=False)
            country_1 = WorldBorder.objects.get(name=results.country_1)
            country_2 = WorldBorder.objects.get(name=results.country_2)
            country_1_name = country_1.name
            country_2_name = country_2.name
            multiplier = round(country_2.area / country_1.area, 1)

            return render(
                request, 'results.html', {
                    'country_1': dummy,
                    'country_1': country_1_name, 
                    'country_2': country_2_name,
                    'multiplier': multiplier,
                    }
                )
        else:
            return render(request, 'error.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = ComparisonForm()
        return render(
            request, 'lookup.html', {'form': form}
        )
```

And finally the html belonging to the form:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Compare the size of two countries here:</h2>
    <form id="comparison" action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form }}

        <input type="submit" name="compare" value="Go compare!">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I am quite new to Django and somewhat at a loss as to how to solve this.

From where I am looking at it, Django is doing exactly what i want it to do (passing the names of two countries so it can compare the size) yet it tells me the form is invalid. How do I solve this? Thanks in advance for your help, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: The immediate problem is that you're passing a values_list to the modelchoicefield, rather than a proper queryset. But I can't understand why you're using a modelform and why you're saving it, even with commit=False, if all you want is two selected countries.

Comment: Thank you taking the time! How would the form with proper modelchoicefield look like? And would this automatically solve the primary key error? The bit below the form.is_valid line still needs some work i realise, but that s for later

Answer (score 0):

My two cents (haven't tested): 1. remove `.values_list('name',flat=True)`

```
country_1 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=WorldBorder.objects.all()
)
country_2 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=WorldBorder.objects.all()
)
```

2. specify a `__str__()` or `__unicode__()` for the `WorldBorder` model.

Answer (score 0):

Learning from the answers I got here (thank you so much all!), this is how i solved it:

1. There is no need to define the POST of the form again as results.
2. As the data in the ComparisonForm is drawn directly from the db, I can use the ids from the form in POST to pull the countries from the database. No need to use the actual country names in querying the db.

So the views.py becomes:

```
def lookup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ComparisonForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # pull country ids from POST and then GET objects from db
            country_1_id = request.POST.get('country_1')
            country_2_id = request.POST.get('country_2')
            country_1_db = WorldBorder.objects.filter(id=country_1_id)
            country_2_db = WorldBorder.objects.filter(id=country_2_id)

            # pull country names and areas
            country_1_name = country_1_db.values_list('name', flat=True)[0]
            country_2_name = country_2_db.values_list('name', flat=True)[0]
            country_1_area = country_1_db.values_list('area', flat=True)[0]
            country_2_area = country_2_db.values_list('area', flat=True)[0]
            multiplier = round(country_2_area / country_1_area, 1)
```

And further as above.